# best_in_place produces wrong JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, error-handling, best-in-place

I did a validation rule for best_in_place field update and it works fine.

But the problem is that following JSON "invalid" response is appeared to be wrongly formated.
Here is how JSON formatted according to inspect:

```
{\"errors\":[\"Project name invalid length 5-120\"],\"status\":\"unprocessable_entity\"}
```

In my controller I have:

```
render :json => {:errors => @project.errors.full_messages, :status => :unprocessable_entity}
```

The rest (js, etc) is taken from original https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place repo.

Can you please just give me a hint what could be a bug that produces those strange "/" you may see in the response...

Thanks in advance

PS:
my first newbiest question

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. `\` is just escape character. It tells to use a quote as symbol in your string. For example:

```
puts "a string"                          # => this is a string
puts "a string with a \" quote"          # => this is a string with a " quote
```

The same is happening with your JSON.

```
require 'json'

{a: 1}.to_json                           # => "{\"a\":1}"
puts("{\"a\":1}")                        # =>  {"a":1}
```

So, when you JSON is printed it would end up looking like this:

```
{"errors":["Project name invalid length 5-120"],"status":"unprocessable_entity"}
```

Comment: Well it seems that I need to dig into how JS processes the JSON response. I still don't understand why validation errors are not passed to the bootstrap alerts. Thanks anyway.